# Laravel database listing error

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to using framework and I tested out Laflux. 
I am able to do "insert" to DB but when list out to tables, I get the error "DataTables warning: table id=datatable-buttons - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7 ". 
Below is the get the data from table. Any idea what went wrong? 
Thanks in advance

```
public function getQuery()
    {
        $filter_trashed = \Input::get('filter_trashed');
        $pages = \DB::table('pages')
                    ->select('id', 'title', 'layout','status', 'created_at');

        if($filter_trashed == 1){
            $pages = $pages->where('deleted_at','<>', NULL);
        }else{
            $pages = $pages->where('deleted_at', NULL);
        }

        return \Datatables::of($pages)
            ->editColumn('sl', '<input type="checkbox" name="cid[]" value="{{$id}}" class="cid_checkbox"/>')
            ->editColumn('status', '@if($status==1) <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"> Published</span> @else <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"> Unpublished</span> @endif')
            ->editColumn('created_at', '{{date("M-j-Y",strtotime($created_at))}}')
            ->make(true);
    }
```

Comment: If you're going to use DataTables with Larave, there is a great package that makes your life much easier. https://datatables.yajrabox.com

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I just started to learn Laravel and hope to get the working copy from the git to work first before changing it. :)